# Auto clear content in column A and B everytime date changed

Tags: excel, vba

Every time date changed, I would like data that I keyed in to be cleared.

For example, today's date is 16 Jan 22, (the date value shown in D2) then in Col A, I typed in Apple, while in the same row (row 2) but in column B, I typed 2. And then I close the Excel file.

So when I open the workbook on 17 Jan 22, I expect the data in column A and column B to be cleared.

Comment: "data in column A and column B to be cleared." on which sheet ?

Comment: Values in column A, column B, and also date values in cell D2 are all in the same sheet.

Comment: Is there only one sheet in the workbook ?

Answer (score 0):

First, define Names in Name Manager for the check cell (D2), eg "DateStamp", and for the range of cells to be cleared (eg "InputData").

Add a Workbook_Open() event handler in the ThisWorkbook project, with this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()       
    Dim dtPrevious As Date
    dtPrevious = Int(Range("DateStamp"))
    
    Dim dtNow As Date
    dtNow = Int(Now())
    
    If dtPrevious <> dtNow Then
        Range("InputData").Value = ""
    End If
    
    Range("DateStamp") = dtNow
End Sub
```